# What is the best way to run .EXE files in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, wine, executable

I have heard about programs like Wine that allow Ubuntu users to run .exe files.

Which program should I use, and how should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Wine allows you to execute a .exe program if you select Wine as a default program for .exe files from Nautilus, open a .exe file using "Open with another application" and select Wine or you execute `wine file.exe` from terminal.

Comment: Files do not need to have the executable bit set to be runnable from Wine. Also, the correct command would be `chmod +x file.exe` to set the executable bit, not `-x`.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit.